# Step through C# application code VS 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to debug some C# source code and I'm not sure how to start debugging properly, i.e. where the code stops at the breakpoints. I have the source code of an in house application. I have inserted break points at the beginning of the code to ensure that it's working. I have set it to Debug, and when I start debugging (press F5), the application will just build the executable. Do i need to attach a process to the executable and debug that, or is there a way to debug from VS 2010 Express?

[image: Main program with a debug point set]

Comment: is it a console application? does it print `stop here` in the *ms-dos* black  window ?

Comment: A couple of sanity checks: Is it a class library? Do you access it from your starting project? If not you have to add reference to the library in your starting project. Also you have to invoke the method you want to debug. Also, if you hit F5 to run the project make sure the program you want to debug is set as start-up project.
If that's not your code maybe disabling Just My Code option in debugger: Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Uncheck "Enable Just my Code"

Comment: @chouaib; It is a windows application. There is no "stop here" displayed. I don't even see the ms-dos window flash up. 
@PiotWolkowski; The start up project is set as Charlotte.MainProgram, Where the "Stop here" line is. The application only seems to run when I select "start without debugging" and it doesn't stop at the breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If the application contains the debug symbols, try the following (in the line above before begin debugging):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried adding this line and it looked like the ms-dos window flashed up, but when i add 'Concole.ReadKey()' after the WriteLine to force it to wait for a response, the window does not stay open. The ms-dos window still seems to flash up, it doesn't even open long enough for me to see if anything is displayed.